# Close fancybox at the end of file upload progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have a script to show a progress bar for when a user is uploading images. This upload form is within an open fancybox that I want to have closed once the images are finished uploading.

If I use a `onclick` event for when the user clicks the submit button to close the fancybox, it will not complete the image upload process.

Here is what I have for the progress bar. I'm wondering if there is a way to close fancybox once the progress bar gives the done message?

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', 'form[profile-picture-data-remote]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fd = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('action'),
          xhr: function() {
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               var total = 0;

               $.each(document.getElementById('profile-image-upload').files, function(i, file) {
                      total += file.size;
               });

               xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                      var loaded = (evt.loaded / total).toFixed(2)*100;
                      $('#progress-container').css({
                          'display': 'block'
                        });
                      $('#progress').text('Uploading... ' + loaded + '%');
                      $('#progress').css({
                        'width': loaded+'%'
                      });
               }, false);
               return xhr;
          },
          type: 'post',
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          data: fd,
          success: function(data) {
            var div = $('<div id="progress" class="uk-progress-bar" style="width: 100%;">Done!</div>')
            $('#progress').replaceWith(div);

// ** IS THERE SOMETHING I CAN DO HERE TO CLOSE FANCYBOX NOW THAT THE IMAGE UPLOAD IS COMPLETE? **
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to close fancybox is `$.fancybox.close()`

If the progress bar is in an IFrame within the fancybox, you'll need to use `parent.$.fancybox.close()`

Replacing your comment in the success method with the appropriate command should work.

Comment: I'm very new to javascript. The progress script is a snippet I found online. what exatly would i need to put to make this work in replace of my comment?
`parent.$.fancybox.close()` ? I don't know the syntax. I tried this and nothing happens then the progress bar shows "Done!" Sorry for the noob question ;)

Comment: @xslibx Try `$.fancybox.close();` first. If that doesn't work then try `parent.$.fancybox.close();`

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the console? (Ctrl + Shift + J to open the console)

Comment: @xslibx Is your code used on a site/page somewhere we could see it?